# How to use nested loops with sequence and a list and how get around of curly braces in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nested-loops, with-statement

I have a code to backup config using the ios_config module. I used ios_facts to get the hostname of devices and I want to use it to put the backup file in a similarly named folder and also use it in the file name itself.

In the last task of my code, I need to loop through two items - the sequence from 0 to 1(or how many items are in my inventory) as I need to access the hostname in the results and use it in the backup options, and also loop through my inventory of devices which I extracted from a csv file. I am aware of the rule of double curly braces but I do not know how to get around it.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Block
      block:
          - name: Use CSV

            csv_to_facts:
              src: '{{playbook_dir}}/NEW/Inventory.csv'
              vsheets:
                - INFO:
                    - IP
                    - OS

          - debug:
              msg: '{{item.IP}}'
            loop: '{{INFO}}'

          - name: Create Inventory
            add_host:
              hostname: '{{item.IP}}'
              ansible_network_os: '{{item.OS}}'
              ansible_user: cisco
              ansible_ssh_pass: cisco
              ansible_connection: network_cli
              ansible_become: yes
              ansible_become_method: enable
              groups: group_01
            loop: '{{INFO}}'


          - name: Gather Facts (IOS)
            ios_facts:
            register: ios_facts_loop
            delegate_to: '{{item}}'
            loop: "{{groups['group_01']}}"


          - name: Backup Switch (IOS)
            ios_config:
              backup: yes
              backup_options:
                dir_path:  "tmp/backups/{{ ios_facts_loop.results.{{item[0]}}.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname }}"
                filename: "{{ios_facts_loop.results.item{{[0]}}.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname}} {{ lookup('pipe','date +%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S')}}"
            register: backup_ios_location
            delegate_to: '{{item[1]}}'
            loop: 
              - with_sequence: "0-{{output|length - 3}}"
              - "{{groups['group_01']}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDR; for vars notation

You cannot add double curly braces inside double curly braces like in your above code. You current var reference:

```
ios_facts_loop.results.{{item[0]}}.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname
```

should be turned to

```
ios_facts_loop.results[item[0]].ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname
# or equivalent
ios_facts_loop.results[item.0].ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname
```

Meanwhile, this will only fix your current syntax error (that you didn't share in your question) as the first element in your loop is a string `'with_sequence: "0-X"'` which therefore has no index 0.

## Attempt to fix the logic

If I understand correctly, for your last task, you just need to loop over the results of your `ios_facts` register and delegate the task to the server it was taken from. Luckilly, you should already have all the info you need in `ios_facts_loop.results`

- It is a list so you can directly loop over it
- Each element should contain an `item` key with the actual item that was used in the previous run at time of register (i.e. one of your `groups['group_01']` element).

So I would try to write your last task like this. **Disclaimer** this is a pure guess as I didn't see your exact datastructure.

```
- name: Backup Switch (IOS)
  ios_config:
    backup: yes
    backup_options:
      dir_path:  "tmp/backups/{{ item.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname }}"
      filename: "{{ item.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname}}{{ lookup('pipe','date +%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S')}}"
  register: backup_ios_location
  delegate_to: '{{item.item}}'
  loop: "{{ ios_facts_loop.results }}"
```

## Going further.

I'm not really familiar with the `ios_*` modules but they should be really close to other stuff I use daily and I think you could really simplify your playbook taking advantage of more ansible feature (e.g. multiple plays in a playbook). I believe the following should actually do the job:

```
---
- name: Construct inventory from CSV  
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Use CSV
      csv_to_facts:
        src: '{{playbook_dir}}/NEW/Inventory.csv'
        vsheets:
          - INFO:
              - IP
              - OS

    - name: Create Inventory
      add_host:
        hostname: '{{item.IP}}'
        ansible_network_os: '{{item.OS}}'
        ansible_user: cisco
        ansible_ssh_pass: cisco
        ansible_connection: network_cli
        ansible_become: yes
        ansible_become_method: enable
        groups: group_01
      loop: '{{INFO}}'

- name: Backup switches from created inventory
  hosts: group_01
  gather_facts: false

  tasks: 
    - name: Get facts from network os                                                                                            
      ios_facts:                                                                                                  
        gather_subset: all 

    - name: Backup Switch (IOS)
      ios_config:
        backup: yes
        backup_options:
          dir_path:  "tmp/backups/{{ ansible_net_hostname }}"
          filename: "{{ ansible_net_hostname }}{{ lookup('pipe','date +%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S') }}"
```

## More background on dot and  brackets notation for vars

You can basically navigate a yaml datastructure with two notation which are equivalent.

- the dot notation

```
a_list_var.index_number
a_hasmap_var.keyname
```

- the brackets notation

```
a_list_var[index_number]
a_hashmap_var['key_name']
```

If we take the following example:

```
my_servers:
  hostA:
    ips:
      - x.x.x.x
      - y.y.y.y
    env:
      shell: bash
      home: somewhere
  hostB:
    ips:
      - a.a.a.a
      - b.b.b.b
    env:
      shell: sh
      home: elsewhere
```

The following notation are all strictly equivalent:

```
# all vars of hostA
hostA_vars: "{{ my_servers.hostA }}"
hostA_vars: "{{ my_server['hostA'] }}"
# first IP of hostB
hostB_ip: "{{ my_servers.hostB.0 }}"
hostB_ip: "{{ my_servers.hostB[0] }}"
hostB_ip: "{{ my_servers['hostB'].0 }}"
hostB_ip: "{{ my_servers['hostB'][0] }}"
```

As you can see, the dot notation tends to be less verbose and more readable. Meanwhile, you cannot use a variable identifier with the dot notation. So If you want to ave the home env of a variable server you would have to use:

```
# set a var for server
server: hostA
# all equivalent again
server_home: "{{ my_servers[server].env.home }}"
server_home: "{{ my_servers[server]['env'].home }}"
server_home: "{{ my_servers[server].env['home'] }}"
server_home: "{{ my_servers[server]['env']['home'] }}"
```

Comment: I had this error after the change: - fatal: localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "dict object has no element 1"}

Comment: I was not fast enough to edit my answer with my comment saying this would fix your syntax error but not your logic which I absolutely didn't get.

Comment: I think I got what your are trying to do... but without your data structure it is hard to give you a good clue. I'll still try an edit.

Comment: Kind of a guess but proposed some changes in my edit. If a step further is needed, please review the help section and more specifically the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) section

Comment: I now understood how to get around the double braces, as you have explained above. Thank you.

Basically I have two entries(192.168.68.101, 192.168.68.102) in my csv file that I used to have a dynamic inventory that I wanted to loop through in my backup task. 

I wanted to loop through my inventory while using the hostname that I got from the ios_facts loop to define my folder name and file name. Below is a snippet of the output. I added the show hostname task to show where I am extracting the hostname.

Comment: TASK [Gather Facts (IOS)] 
ok: [localhost -> 192.168.68.201] => (item=192.168.68.201)
ok: [localhost -> 192.168.68.202] => (item=192.168.68.202)
TASK [Show Hostname from Facts] 
ok: [] => (item=0) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "ios_facts_loop.results.0.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname": "R1",
    "item": "0"
}
ok: [] => (item=1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "ios_facts_loop.results.1.ansible_facts.ansible_net_hostname": "R2",
    "item": "1"
}
TASK [Backup Switch (IOS)] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "dict object has no element 1"}

Comment: Have a look at my last edit and my proposition for a much simpler playbook. I could not test so you may have to adapt but I don't see why it would not work. Your really don't need all those loops and registers. Just use ansible how it's meant to be.

Comment: I think we are getting closer. I got this error when I run your proposed code:
fatal: [192.168.68.201]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_net_hostname' is undefined

I think we still need to loop through the module ios_facts since the variable ansible_net_hostname is defined there.

Comment: It seems that `ios_facts` is not ran automatically with `gather_facts: true` as I thought. Just changed my alt playbook to reintroduce it. Let me know if ti fixes the problem.

Comment: It works now. Just added the ios_facts before the backup task. Thanks man.